# Some question about set equality involving natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_n = \{ ny: y \in \mathbb{N} \}$, that is the set of multiple of $y$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. E.g: $A_1 = \{1, 2 ,3 ,...\}, A_2=\{2,4,6,... \}$

Consider the following set:

$$ \mathbb{N} \setminus \{x \} \stackrel{?}{=} \bigcup_{n \ne x} A_n$$ 
, where $x$ is any fixed natural number.

Clearly the $\supset$ direction is obvious, but I am a bit stuck at the reverse direction. Though my speculation is that $\subset$ holds too.

Comment: If $x\ne1$, isn't $A_1$ in the right hand side?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Ah you are right about this one. This obviously breaks down when $x = 1$, which I totally forget about out of so many numbers that I could think of.

Comment: "the set of multiple of $y$" --- should be "the set of multiples of $n$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the $\supset$ direction does not hold.

Take, for example, $x = 2$.  Then $2 \notin \mathbb N \setminus \{ 2 \}$.  But $\displaystyle 2 \in A_1 \subset \bigcup_{n \ne 2} A_n$.

However, the $\subset$ direction does hold:

Case $1$: If $x \ne 1$, then $\displaystyle \mathbb N = A_1 \subset \bigcup_{n \ne x} A_n$.

Case $2$: If $x = 1$, then

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{ x \} &\implies k \in A_k \\
&\implies k \in \bigcup_{n \ne x} A_n
\end{align*}

Comment: The interesting observation is that $\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}=\bigcup_{\mbox{$p$ prime}}A_p$. Furstenberg used this to argue "topologically" that there are infinitely many primes.